# Extracting URI from web pages via BASH

Tags: regex, bash

I need to pull all the links for a page that resides on an Intranet however am unsure how best to do it. The structure of the site is as follows

**List of topics**

1. Topic 1
2. Topic 2
3. Topic 3

etc

Now the links reside in each of the topic pages. I want to avoid going through in excess of 500 topic pages manually to extract the URI.

Each of the topic pages has the following structure

`http://alias/filename.php?cat=6&number=1`

The `cat` parameter refers to the category and the `number` parameter refers to the topic.

Once in the topic page the URI I need to extract exists in a particular format again

`http://alias/value?id=somevalue`

**Caveats**

1. I don't have access to the database so the option to trawl through it is not an option
2. There is only ever a single URI in each topic page
3. I need to extract the list to a file that simply lists each URI in a new line

I would like to execute some sort of script I can run from the terminal via BASH that will trawl through the topical URI and then the URI in each of the topics.

**In a nutshell**

How can I extract a list using a script I can run using BASH that will recursively go through all the list of topics and then extract the URI in each of the topic pages and spit out a text file with the each of extracted URI in a new line.

Comment: @Qtax - The question is how can I extract a list using a script I can run using BASH. Updated my question with the specific nature of my requirements. Let me know if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implement this with Perl, using the HTML::TokeParser and WWW::Mechanize modules:

```
use HTML::TokeParser;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $site = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck =>1);
my $topicmax = 500;  #Note:  adjust this to the number of topic pages you have

# loop through each topic page
foreach(1..$topicmax) {
    my $topicurl = "http://alias/filename.php?cat=6&number=$_";

    # get the page
    $site->get($topicurl);
    $p = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$site->{content});

    # parse the page and extract the links
    while (my $token = $p->get_tag("a")) {
        my $url = $token->[1]{href};
        # use a regex to test for the link format we want
        if($url =~ /^http:\/\/alias\/value\?id=/) {
            print "$url\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The script prints to stdout, so you just need to redirect it to a file.

Comment: Awesome. Will give it a go. I'll have to check whether PERL is installed on my device. Do I need to install both the modules you mentioned?

Comment: As aside I have never used PERL, would it be lengthy to explain what each of the functions do in the code you posted? If it is don't worry, I'll just need to read heaps.

Comment: Since you're using bash, I assume you're on Linux or unIx. If so, perl should already be installed. You will have to install the modules, though. Google "perl module installation on <your OS>" to see how. Usually not too painful. Also suggest you get the classic O'reilly text "Learning Perl" and work through the problems at the end of each chapter. Lots of material on the web, also.

Comment: Yup. Running Ubuntu LTS 12.04. Thanks for the suggestions. Will have a go at understanding the code.

Comment: Is there a way in the code I can get it to also output it to a file? Would be as easy as `print "$url\n" > "output.txt";`

Comment: On Ubuntu, use apt-get to install perl modules (you'll need sudo access).  For example, for WWW::Mechanize:  sudo apt-get install libwww-mechanize-perl.

Comment: In a bash shell, anything output to stdout can be re-directed to a file using '>' which overwrites or '>>' which appends.  So, all you need to do is to paste the code into a file and give it a name with a .pl extension (say linkfinder.pl).  Then from the command line:  perl linkfinder.pl > myfile.txt.

Comment: I take it that `apt-get to install perl modules` will install both `HTML::TokeParser` and `WWW::Mechanize`?

Comment: Right - you could do that with the following single command:  sudo apt-get install libwww-mechanize-perl libhtml-tokeparser-simple-perl

Comment: What is the difference between `perl-modules` and `libwww-mechanize-perl` & `libhtml-tokeparser-simple-perl`?

Comment: Both of those are Perl modules.  You can look them up on CPAN (http://www.cpan.org/). Basically, mechanize automates navigation, button clicks, and form submittal, while tokeparser parses the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I take it that when you say both you are referring to `libwww-mechanize-perl` and `libhtml-tokeparser-simple-perl` but do I also need to install the `perl-modules` package?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  I don't even know what the "perl-modules package" is.  You just need to run the 'apt-get' command I mentioned a few comments above, then you should be able to run the script.

Comment: Just thought would let you know that the script has saved countless hours. So again, thanks a bundle.